# Scrape Ebay sold listings using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to pull info from ebay sold listings (title of listing, price, number of bids, date, time, number of reviews of seller)

I am having trouble and get an error I don't see anything on Google on:

```
url <- "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=kobe+bryant+rookie+card&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&LH_Sold=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&LH_Auction=1&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=15&_stpos=92653&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D1&_salic=1&_sop=12&_dmd=1&_ipg=50&LH_Complete=1&_fosrp=1"

webpage <- url %>% read_html()
```

I get the following error
Error in readBin(11L, "raw", 65536L) : Failed writing data

Any guidance in connecting r to the url so I could figure it out from there would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could use RSelenium to solve your url problem.

Below a possible solution.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser= 'firefox', port = 4551L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]] 
remote_driver$navigate(url)
webpage <- remote_driver$getPageSource() %>% unlist() %>% read_html()
```